# Can I use Sony SDK v2 with Basic4android?

Tags: sdk, sony, basic4android, sony-smartwatch

Can I use the Sony SDK v2 with Basic4android? Want touch event and sensor data in my app to evaluate. Does anyone have an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to use the Sony Add-on SDK in combination with other SDKs and libraries. On the smartphone side, you can use Basic4Android to create the user interface. But on the Smartwatch2 you have to use the Sony Add-on SDK, since Basic4android has no support for it.

You can wrap your Java code with Smartwatch support as a library and then reference it from Basic4android IDE. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/tool-simple-library-compiler-build-libraries-without-eclipse.29918/#post-173756) on Basic4Android.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am new with this. My question : is it possible to create a library from one of the code examples (SmartExtensionUtils ? ) and use it to control the extension ?

Comment: it would be very cool to find a library for smart extensions here: http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/wiki/index.php/Libraries